# How to fix The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Before I start my project I don't get any error, but when I start it I get this error

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.

the error is in this code

```
public class RoleMenu{
   private DBContext db = new DBContext();
   public List<Menu> GetList_Menu_ByRole(Role role)
   {
        List<RoleMenu> roleMenus = db.RoleMenus.Include(u => u.Role).Include(u => u.Menu).ToList(); //error is here
        List<Menu> roles = new List<Menu>();
        foreach (var eachRoleMenu in roleMenus)
        {
              if (eachRoleMenu.RoleID == role.ID)
              {
                  roles.Add(eachRoleMenu.Menu);
              }
        }
        return roles;
  }
}
```

and this is my web.config

```
  <add name="DBContext" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-SRRO03Q;Initial Catalog=Project1;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

How to fix this error? thanks,

Comment: The code doesnt show the source of the error, its related to your 'db' variable holding the database context. Can you share some code that shows the lifetiime of 'db'?

Comment: add your connection codes please. check connection is closed ' con.Close(); '

Comment: I have edited my code, only that on that page, besides only ordinary functions @NijinKoderi

Comment: I have edited my code, only that on that page, besides only ordinary functions @MichaelSander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still doesnt show the proper error source, 
but in general, I would never keep a private variable of a `DBContext`, unless in very rare cases. You would need to make your class `RoleMenu` implement `IDisposable` and use it properly.

I suggest you use one context per query, like this:

```
public class RoleMenu
{
    public List<Menu> GetList_Menu_ByRole(Role role)
    {
        using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
        {
            List<RoleMenu> roleMenus = db.RoleMenus.Include(u => u.Role).Include(u => u.Menu).ToList(); //error is here
            List<Menu> roles = new List<Menu>();
            foreach (var eachRoleMenu in roleMenus)
            {
                if (eachRoleMenu.RoleID == role.ID)
                {
                    roles.Add(eachRoleMenu.Menu);
                }
            }

            return roles;
        }
    }
}
```